# How to create login for this url in php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, phpmyadmin

This is `angularjs` code. I have to create login using `php` for this link. I created `loginnewmob.php` file. but it is not working properly. I know this is wrong.

How to write login for this using `php`.

**service.js**

```
'use strict';


angular.module('Authentication')

.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

    service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

        /* Dummy authentication for testing, uses $timeout to simulate api call
         ----------------------------------------------*/

     /*   $timeout(function(){
            var response = { success: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
            if(!response.success) {
                response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
            }
            callback(response);
        }, 1000);*/

        /* Use this for real authentication
         ----------------------------------------------*/
        $http.post('http://localhost/webservice/loginnewmob.php', { username: username, password: password })
            .success(function (response) {
                callback(response);
            });

    };

    service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
        var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

        $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: username,
                authdata: authdata
            }
        };

        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
    };

    service.ClearCredentials = function () {
        $rootScope.globals = {};
        $cookieStore.remove('globals');
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
    };

    return service;
}])


.factory('Base64', function () {
    /* jshint ignore:start */


var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

return {
    encode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        do {
            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
                keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc4);
            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    },

    decode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
        var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
        if (base64test.exec(input)) {
            window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
                "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
                "Expect errors in decoding.");
        }
        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        do {
            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    }
};

/* jshint ignore:end */
});
```

**loginnewmob.php**

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");


$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","user_auth_tutorial");
$res= mysqli_query($con,"Select * from newuser where username='$username' and password='$password'");
$result = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$result[] = $row;
}  
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? is the php file getting called?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/webservice/loginnewmob.php. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.` 

This is my error

Comment: send headers along with your post request,
`$http.post(url, data, {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
});` here is an example.

Comment: hello Sravan, Now I have this error. `Can't find variable: data`

Comment: `data` means not the `data`, those are your parameteres,
`$http.post('http://localhost/webservice/loginnewmob.php', { username: username, password: password },{ headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' } })`

Comment: change it to the above code.

Comment: yes but not working properly